# Struggle with & symbol

Tags: symbols, ampersand

I'm facing a problem that I don't understand the issue. I want to type the "&" symbol in latex. [detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html) says just to use `\&` and I did, but this weird symbol was what printed:

[image]

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

P.S. When I copy the symbol to paste it here it will be "&"! So it is indeed "&" but in a weird shape that I haven't seen. How can I print it in the more common shape?

Comment: The "weird shape you haven't seen" is called the *italic* font shape.

Comment: the form you show is actually less weird than & form. the symbol is a compressed "et" latin for *and". The constituent letters are clearer in the italic version shown

Answer (score 1):

It is solved by doing this:

```
\textup{\&}
```

Comment: but if the surrounding text is italic it would be more natural to use the & from the same font as you show in the question